# Postman collection Authorization not present in documentation headers

Tags: jwt, http-headers, authorization, postman, postman-collection

I have started using Postman to map out my API and also wanted have a quick, easy way to document it and share it.

My API is using JWT for auth and this token needs to be present in each request except login.

In order to keep it DRY I have used Postman collection Authorization 
 as explained on their blog http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/12/13/keep-it-dry-with-collection-and-folder-elements/

[Example of how I set up collection authorization  type bearer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVmsj.png)

This header is being used by my API as type "Inherit auth from parent" and this works with no problems during my requests.

But if I choose to view collection in browser this header is not displayed in the request or examples see screenshot.

[Collection documentation as viewed in web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erpWZ.png)

Here is the cURL request in Postman:

`curl -X GET \
  https://example.api/v1/auth/user \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

**Is it possible to display the auth header while using the collection settings** or I should add the header myself for each request in order to make sure that this is added in the examples and documentation?

*Edit:*
I've found that if I hover over the Authorization header I get the following message:

> This temporary header is generated by Postman and is not saved with your request.

[Here is a screenshot from the app with Postman collection temporary headers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJ0oN.png)

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Already posted in their forum and submitted a support ticket. Did you find a solution in the end?

Comment: No solution, but I mentioned in description/introduction that Authorization header is expected to be present in each request with login as exception.

Comment: I am not sure I am going to say something worth so I will paste as comment instead of answer. Did you look for your temporary headers? Did you enable them? Take a look at https://community.getpostman.com/t/temporary-headers/5243

Answer (score 1):

This issue will fix in 2 or 3 mounths.

You can track the issue status in https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/projects/40#card-33062423

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting up that JWT Token as request headers then it should get displayed in the documentation. Below are the Steps how i am generating and setting up jwt token:

1. Login api to generate jwt token.
2. saving that token as environment
3. variable Using that variable in each request which requires
   Authorization header.

please see the screenshot 
[image]

Comment: As you said this method requires that each request defines the authorization header. At the moment I have this set at collection level. Seems that Postman updated some things in their end.
At least now each endpoint under auth will display this message: "This request is using an authorization helper from collection <CollectionName>"